# Free drive image with file level restore

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup

A friend of mine's brother purchased a new PC and wants to transfer the data from the old PC to the new PC. They ran the Windows File and Transfer Settings wizard which grabbed all that stuff, but they want to do a full backup of the drive to an external USB drive they purchased in case they missed anything.

Normally I'd do this with a USB stick running Linux and a quick run of rsync, but I'm 300 miles away from them right now. I suggested DriveImage XML as I'd used it in the past, but I guess it makes you pay to restore if you are using an external drive? The last time I used it you could image it and do file level restore for free.

Does anyone else have any suggestions on software that will allow them to do an easy full drive backup with file level restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builtin Windows Backup also does the same thing.  A full backup can be restored file by file using either the UI or be simply mounting the backup as a virtual harddrive (Full backups are stored as a vhd file).